# how to have numbers output with commas

Tags: javascript, html, function, calculator

I am trying to create a simple mortgage calculator and I want to have the numbers print with commas when the outputted number is larger than 3 digits. I would appreciate any help or suggestions. Im not really good at JS so I'd appreciate an example of where I'd put the code to allow it to print a comma. Thank you guys!

**JS Code**

```
 var results;
        
        function clearResults() {
            $(".form__error").html("");
            $('.results').html("");
        };
    
        $(function(){
            $('body').on('submit','form',{},function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); 
                // clear previous results
                clearResults();
                // get our inputs
                var rawInputs = $(this).serializeArray();
                // convert these to numbers and create our argument array
                var args = {};
                for(var i = 0; i < rawInputs.length; i++) {
                    args[rawInputs[i].name] = parseFloat(rawInputs[i].value);
                }
                // run the mortgage calculator
                results = mortgageCalculators.monthlyMortgagePayments(args);
                if(results.error) {
                    $(".form__error").html(results.error);
                } else {
                    $('.results').html(results)
                }
            });
        });

!function(){function e(e,t){var r={error:!1,data:e};for(var o in t){if(t[o].isRequired&&void 0==e[o]){r.error=o+" is required.";break}if(t[o].isNumber&&("number"!=typeof e[o]||isNaN(e[o]))){r.error=o+" must be a number.";break}if(t[o].isNotNegative&&e[o]<0){r.error=o+" must be a positive number.";break}if(t[o].isNotZero&&0==e[o]){r.error=o+" must be greater then 0.";break}if(t[o].isNotFloat&&e[o]%1!=0){r.error=o+" must be an integer value.";break}}return r}function t(e,t){return e*t}function r(e){var t=e.loanAmount,r=0==e.interestRate?0:e.interestRate/100,o=0==r?0:r/12,i=12*e.termInYears;return o*t*Math.pow(1+o,i)/(Math.pow(1+o,i)-1)}function o(e){var t=e.monthlyPrincipalPayment,r=0==e.interestRate?0:e.interestRate/100,o=0==r?0:r/12,i=12*e.termInYears;return t*(Math.pow(1+o,i)-1)/(o*Math.pow(1+o,i))}function i(e){return isNaN(parseFloat(e.toFixed(2)))?0:parseFloat(e.toFixed(2))}window.mortgageCalculators={},window.mortgageCalculators.monthlyMortgagePayments=function(t){var o=e(t,{loanAmount:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1},interestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},termInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0}});return o.error?{error:o.error}:i(r(t))},window.mortgageCalculators.monthlyMortgagePaymentsWithExtraPayments=function(o){var a=e(o,{loanAmount:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1},interestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},termInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},extraPaymentAmount:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1}});if(a.error)return{error:a.error};for(var s=o.interestRate/100/12,n=12*o.termInYears,N=o.extraPaymentAmount,m=r({loanAmount:o.loanAmount,interestRate:o.interestRate,termInYears:o.termInYears}),u=o.loanAmount,l=0,g=m,R=0;R<=n;R++){u-(c=m-(v=t(s,u)))>=0?u>=g&&(u-=c):u-=g=u,u>0&&(l+=m)}var y=m+N;u=o.loanAmount;var d=[];for(R=0;R<=n;R++){var v,c;u-(c=m-(v=t(s,u))+N)>=0?u>=y&&(u-=c):u-=y=u,u>0&&d.push({monthlyPayment:i(m+N),principalPayment:i(c),interestPayment:i(v),balance:i(u)})}for(var b=[],f=0;f<=Math.ceil(d.length);f+=12)b.push(d.slice(f,f+12));for(var h=[],I=o.loanAmount,F=0;F<b.length;F++){for(var P=0,p=0,q=0;q<b[F].length;q++)P+=b[F][q].interestPayment,p+=b[F][q].principalPayment;I-p>=0?I>=p&&(I-=p):I-=p=I,h.push({annualInterestPayment:i(P),annualPrincipalPayment:i(p),balance:i(I),monthlyBreakdown:b[F]})}return{withExtraPayment:{totalMonthlyPayment:i(m+N),interestRate:o.interestRate,term:o.termInYears,totalCost:i(d.length*(m+N)),payments:h},withoutExtraPayment:{totalMonthlyPayment:i(m),interestRate:o.interestRate,term:o.termInYears,totalCost:i(l)}}},window.mortgageCalculators.howMuchCanIBorrow=function(t){var r=e(t,{interestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},termInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},grossMonthlyIncome:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},downPayment:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},monthlyDebtPayment:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},yearlyPropertyTax:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},yearlyPropertyInsurance:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1}});if(r.error)return{error:r.error};var a=t.interestRate,s=t.termInYears,n=t.monthlyDebtPayment,N=t.grossMonthlyIncome,m=t.downPayment/100,u=t.yearlyPropertyTax/12+t.yearlyPropertyInsurance/12,l=.36,g=.43,R=o({termInYears:s,interestRate:a,monthlyPrincipalPayment:l*N-n-u}),y=o({termInYears:s,interestRate:a,monthlyPrincipalPayment:g*N-n-u});return{conservative:{priceOfHome:i(R+R*m),downPayment:i(R*m),loanAmount:i(R)},aggressive:{priceOfHome:i(y+y*m),downPayment:i(y*m),loanAmount:i(y)},futureMonthlyPayment:{conservative:{principalAndInterest:i(l*N-n),taxesAndInsurance:i(u),totalMonthlyPayment:i(l*N-n+u)},aggressive:{principalAndInterest:i(g*N-n),taxesAndInsurance:i(u),totalMonthlyPayment:i(g*N-n+u)}}}},window.mortgageCalculators.compareFifteenVsThirtyYearMortgages=function(t){var o=e(t,{loanAmount:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1},interestRate1:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},interestRate2:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1}});if(o.error)return{error:o.error};var a=t.loanAmount,s=t.interestRate1,n=t.interestRate2,N=r({loanAmount:a,interestRate:s,termInYears:15}),m=r({loanAmount:a,interestRate:n,termInYears:30});return{fifteenYearMortgage:{monthlyMortgagePayment:i(N),totalInterest:i(15*N*12-a),totalPayments:i(15*N*12)},thirtyYearMortgage:{monthlyMortgagePayment:i(m),totalInterest:i(30*m*12-a),totalPayments:i(30*m*12)}}},window.mortgageCalculators.refinanceMortgage=function(o){var a=e(o,{loanAmount:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1},interestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},termInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},newInterestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},newTermInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},newTermInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},paymentsMade:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!0}});if(a.error)return{error:a.error};for(var s=o.loanAmount,n=o.interestRate,N=o.termInYears,m=o.newInterestRate,u=o.newTermInYears,l=o.paymentsMade,g=r({loanAmount:s,interestRate:n,termInYears:N}),R=s,y=0,d=0;d<l;d++){var v=t(n/100/12,R),c=g-v;R-c>=0&&(R-=c),c,y+=v}var b=g*N*12-s-y,f=R,h=r({loanAmount:f,interestRate:m,termInYears:u}),I=h*u*12-R;return{interestSaved:i(b-I),oldMonthlyMortgage:{monthlyMortgagePayment:i(g),remainingInterest:i(b)},newMonthlyMortgage:{newMortgageTotal:i(f),monthlyMortgagePayment:i(h),remainingInterest:i(I)}}},window.mortgageCalculators.comparefixedRateVsARM=function(o){var a=e(o,{loanAmount:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1},interestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},termInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},monthsBeforeFirstAdjustment:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},monthsBetweenAdjustments:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},expectedAdjustmentRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},initialInterestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},maximumInterestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1}});if(a.error)return{error:a.error};for(var s=o.interestRate,n=o.termInYears,N=o.loanAmount,m=o.initialInterestRate,u=o.expectedAdjustmentRate,l=o.monthsBeforeFirstAdjustment,g=o.monthsBetweenAdjustments,R=o.maximumInterestRate,y=r({loanAmount:N,interestRate:s,termInYears:n}),d=r({loanAmount:N,interestRate:m,termInYears:n}),v=N,c=0;c<l;c++){v-=d-t(m/100/12,v)}for(var b=m+u,f=r({loanAmount:v,interestRate:b,termInYears:n-l/12}),h=0;h<g;h++){v-=f-t(b/100/12,v)}for(var I,F=12*n-l-g,P=0;P<F;P+=g){b<R?b+=u:b=R,f=r({loanAmount:v,interestRate:b,termInYears:(F-P)/12});for(var p=0;p<g;p++){v-=f-t(b/100/12,v)}I=f}return response={fixedRate:{monthlyMortgagePaymentARM:i(y)},ARM:{initialMonthlyMortgagePayment:i(d),maxMonthlyMortgagePayment:i(I)}},response},window.mortgageCalculators.compareBuyVsRent=function(o){var a=e(o,{monthlyRent:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1},purchasePrice:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!1},downPayment:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},interestRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},termInYears:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},howLongBeforeSelling:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!0,isNotFloat:!0},incomeTaxRate:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},expectedAnnualRentIncrease:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},closingCosts:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1},annualAppreciation:{isRequired:!0,isNumber:!0,isNotNegative:!0,isNotZero:!1,isNotFloat:!1}});if(a.error)return{error:a.error};for(var s=o.monthlyRent,n=o.expectedAnnualRentIncrease,N=o.purchasePrice,m=o.downPayment/100*N,u=N-m,l=o.interestRate,g=o.termInYears,R=o.closingCosts/100*u,y=o.howLongBeforeSelling,d=o.incomeTaxRate,v=o.annualAppreciation,c=r({loanAmount:u,interestRate:l,termInYears:g}),b=0,f=0,h=0,I=N,F=0,P=m,p=0;p<y;p++){F+=12*s,s+=s*(n/100),I+=I*(v/100);for(var q=0;q<12;q++){var w=t(l/100/12,u),A=c-w;u-A>=0?u>=A&&(u-=A):u-=A=u,f+=A,b+=w,h+=w*(d/100)}}var Z=I-u,M=(P+=f+b-h+(u+R))-I;return{currentValueOfHome:i(I),totalOwedToBank:i(u),equityOnHome:i(Z),netCostOfBuying:i(M),netCostOfRenting:i(F),benefitOfBuying:i(F-M)}}}();
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="loan-calculator">
            <div class="top">
                <h2>Monthly Mortgage Payment Calculator</h2>
                <br /><br/>
            <form action="#">
        <div class="group">
            <div class="title">Loan Amount</div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="loanAmount" id="loanAmount" >
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="title" >Interest Rate</div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="interestRate" id="interestRate">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="title">Term (Years)</div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="0" name="termInYears" id="termInYears">
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="result">
            <div class="left">
                <br /><br />
                <h3>Monthly mortgage payment of</h3>
                <div class="results value"></div>




            <button class="calculate-btn-mortgage" type="submit">Calculate </button>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you can write it with regex and replace number with string at show time:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

or you can do this too:

```
var n = 34523453.345;
console.log(n.toLocaleString());  // "34,523,453.345"
```